# The "ext" folder is missing in bundle jre

Tags: java, maven, javafx

- i develop one javafx application.
- And i deploy that application with the help of javafx-maven-pluging provided by com.zenjava.
- First i create jar(mvn jfx:jar) and then i create native bundle that is .msi(mvn jfx:native) on windows.
- In native bundle the private copy of jre is present but it does not contain "ext" folder which is come up with regular jre7.
- the jar present in "ext" folder required for the cryptography purpose and need it in my application
- so how i can include the "ext" in jre at the time of creating bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try it with jdk 7 update 40 and above.

[Oracle JDK download latest update](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)